# How do i remove or merge duplicated values in my JSON List?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

My Json looks like this,

```
[
    {
        "MatchNumber": 1,
        "RoundNumber": 1,
        "HomeTeam": "Crystal Palace",
        "AwayTeam": "Liverpool",
        "Group": null,
        "HomeTeamScore": 0,
        "AwayTeamScore": 2
    },
    {
        "MatchNumber": 16,
        "RoundNumber": 2,
        "HomeTeam": "Fulham",
        "AwayTeam": "Liverpool",
        "Group": null,
        "HomeTeamScore": 2,
        "AwayTeamScore": 2
    },
    {
        "MatchNumber": 11,
        "RoundNumber": 2,
        "HomeTeam": "Arsenal",
        "AwayTeam": "Leicester",
        "Group": null,
        "HomeTeamScore": 4,
        "AwayTeamScore": 2
    },
    {
        "MatchNumber": 191,
        "RoundNumber": 20,
        "HomeTeam": "Arsenal",
        "AwayTeam": "Leeds",
        "Group": null,
        "HomeTeamScore": null,
        "AwayTeamScore": null
    }
]
```

for this Json example, using this list will produce 2 Arsenal in the HomeTeam and 2 Liverpool AwayTeam in the dropdown list.

here's my controller code so far, i tried set but it only reordered the list, didn't remove duplicated teams.

```
@Controller
public class CCController {
private static final String MAIN_PAGE = "main";
private static final String JSON_URL = "https://randomfootball.com/json/epl-2022";
  @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model, @ModelAttribute Team team){
       List<Team> teams = (List<Team>) parsingService.parse(JSON_URL);
       Set<Team> targetSet = new HashSet<>(teams);
       model.addAttribute("teamList", targetSet);    
        return MAIN_PAGE;
    }
}
```

here is my Team model, added as per request.
thanks for any guidance

```
public class Team{
    
    public Team() {
    }
    
    Set<String> HomeTeam;
    
    public Set<String> getHomeTeam() {
        return HomeTeam;
    }

    public void setHomeTeam(Set<String> homeTeam) {
        HomeTeam = homeTeam;
    }

    public static Set<String> keySet() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I finally got a list that doesn't duplicate.
I did it by getting the object from the array of Json. Build that into JsonArray, then use set. That requires a dependency, jakarta.json.

Comment: Can you show the class Team? Generally speaking, if you expect to get 2 values when moving to Set but you still get 4 like in List is most probably because the class Team doesn't implement equals and hashCode correctly

Comment: I just updated with my team model.
not sure how to use equals and hashCode.

Comment: At the moment you have a set of teams which each contain a set of home teams? Is that what you intend? At the very least you need to implement a hashcode and equals method. They can be generated by the idea or they are quite simple (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-equals-hashcode gives a simple overview).

Comment: my desired output is a dropdown list with a list of home teams(away team is optional) that doesn't have any duplicated value. how the team is arranged is flexible.

Comment: You're modeling your data the wrong way. Each entry of the JSON list is a Match, not a Team, so your parsing service should return a list of matches and not of teams. Then, out of that list of matches, it's enough to stream on the list, map to home team (which is a string) and collect to set which will contain the unique values of the home teams.

Comment: I did it by getting the object from the array of Json. build into JsonArray, then set, thanks everyone.